# Can someone fix my php echo statement?

Tags: php, html

```
echo "<a href=\"http://bans.scavengercraft.com/index.php?action=viewplayer&player=" . $_POST["player"] . "&server=0">Click Here</a>";
```

Can someone please fix this? I keep getting errors and i really am confused...

I'm trying to make it so it echos a changed url using a form.

My form:

```
<body>

    <h1>Enter Player Name.</h1>

    <form method="post" action="handler.php">
        <input type="text" name="player">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

</body>
```

If you can, can you tell me how to make it so when the "Submit" button is pressed it auto redirects them in a new tab to the edited url? If you could, it would be amazing!

Comment: escape this quote `..=0">..`

Comment: If it's an <a></a> tag shouldn't the end of the url be closed?

Comment: This is about a simple a syntax problem as you're likely to encounter. Just looking at the syntax-highlighted code should make the problem very obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick. When using quotation marks you can put the PHP variable direction inside the string. Then you can change the quotes around the url to single quotes so it doesn't close out of the string.

```
echo "<a href='http://bans.scavengercraft.com/index.php?action=viewplayer&player=$_POST[player]&server=0'>Click Here</a>";
```

Comment: nuge nuge, array key quoteing please

Comment: @MrBumtart mark the question as correct if it solved your problem.

Comment: @MrBumtart, make it a habit (good habit) to accept the answer to show your appreciation towards the effort of answer owner.

Comment: I couldn't accept it at the time. There was a time limit.